Nearest integer to fractional power series
Let $k$ be a positive integer. Let
$$\displaystyle f_0(x) = a_n x^{\frac{n}{k}} + \cdots + a_1 x^{\frac{1}{k}} + a_0 + \sum_{h \geq 1} a_{-h} x^{-\frac{h}{k}}$$
be a Laurent series in the variable $x^{-1/k}$ with all coefficients lying in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $T$ be a positive integer, and let $f_1(x), \cdots, f_m(x)$ be defined by
$$\displaystyle f_j(x) = f_0(x) + \sum_{h \geq T} a(h,j) x^{-\frac{h}{k}}$$
where $a(h,j) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $1 \leq j \leq m$ and $h \geq T$.
For a real number $\alpha$, let $[\alpha]$ be the nearest integer to $\alpha$ (so it is equal to $\lfloor \alpha \rfloor$ if the fractional part of $\alpha$ is less than or equal to $1/2$, and equal to $\lceil \alpha \rceil$ if the fractional part is greater than $1/2$).
Under what hypotheses on $f_j(x), 0 \leq j \leq m$ can we guarantee that there exist infinitely many integers $x$ such that
$$\displaystyle [f_0(x)] - f_j(x)$$
is positive for an odd number of indices $j = 0, 1, \cdots, m$ and there exist infinitely many integers $y$ such that
$$\displaystyle [f_0(y)] - f_j(y)$$
is positive for an even number of indices $j = 0, 1, \cdots, m$?
